# Count variables based on response in Access

Tags: ms-access

I have a table with a few Yes/No variables. How can I create a query that will count the amount of records answered "Yes" for each variable?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Can you provide more information about your table structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just sum the Yes/No fields in a query and this will give you negative numbers - i.e. if there are a total of 4 yes's the result will be  -4. If you want positive numbers add a field to the query that will change the -1/0 of a Yes/No field to 1 or 0.

Here's a query based on a table with two yes no fields with the results as negative and positive.

```
SELECT Sum(tblTest.Opt1) AS SumOfOpt1, Sum(IIf([Opt1],1,0)) AS SumOpt1Value FROM tblTest;
```

The results will be SumOfOpt1 = -4 and SumOpt1Value = 4

Answer (score 1):

You can do it two ways, depending on how you want your display needs to be, One Row for Yes and One for No, then you can use,

```
SELECT
    yesnoFieldName,
    Count(someField)
FROM
    yourTableName
GROUP BY 
    yesnoFieldName;
```

If you want just two columns one for Yes and One for No, then you can use,

```
SELECT
    SUM(IIF(yesnoFieldName = True, 1, 0)) As TotalYes,
    SUM(IIF(yesnoFieldName = False, 1, 0)) As TotalNo
FROM
    yourTableName;
```